# Remote execution with on a Single node with Multiple GPU

Tags: fb-hydra

I am looking into documentation for running hydra on a single node remotely. I am looking for methods where I can run a code present in my local machine and to run it on a GCP instance.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a [Hydra Launcher](https://hydra.cc/docs/1.0/advanced/plugins/#launcher) that supports GCP.

For now, Hydra does not support this. We do have a Ray Launcher that launches to AWS and could be further extended to launching on GCP. Feel free to subscribe this [issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1753).